# Google Play in-app installation of referenced app

Tags: android, installation, google-play, in-app

**Does Google Play provides mechanism to install other app** (probably related, e.g. from the same developer) **without going to the Google Play app directly**?

Most probably feature is similar to [In-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) or [In-app review](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review).

From my perspective it looks like this:

1. Current app launches some intent (or uses some API) with pointing on package name of referenced app from GP.
2. User sees the popup with details about the referenced app (info taken from GP) and ability to install.
3. User press install button that starts installation process (source `apk` is from GP) without exiting current app.
4. Referenced app installed and can be then used as usual.

P.S. I found an example at Fb app, and it looks like this:
[image: Instant AliExpress install]

Answer (score 0):

Desired behavior (popup with possibility of installation) can be provided only with [App campaigns](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6247380?hl=en).
So, if I understand correctly, direct usage of such component is not available.